# Roslaunch can't locate node, but rosrun works fine

Tags: roslaunch, catkin-make, ros-kinetic, rospy, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on a simple node written entirely in python. To make it work with roslaunch, I made it into a package. I got the package working fine, and I can run `rosrun my_package controller` just fine. However, when I run it in a roslaunch file, it gives the error  `ERROR: cannot launch node of type [my_package/controller]: can't locate node [controller] in package [my_package]` What is wrong with my environment or package?
As a minimal example, I get this with the simple launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
        <node pkg="my_package" type="controller" name="controller"/>
</launch>
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Changing the name of the executable from "controller" to "controller.py" (And adjusting in the launch file)
2. Setting 777 permissions on the executable
3. Relaunching the terminal
4. `source`ing .bashrc again (which has setup.bash in it)
5. Rerunning `catkin_make` a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291235/roslaunch-can%27t-locate-node,-but-rosrun-works-fine/) by [billtheplatypus](https://answers.ros.org/users/35184/billtheplatypus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2018-05-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
The name of the file should not influence this at all. To verify, I just created a toy workspace with a single `rospy` pkg that contains a `controller` file containing the default Talker node. After building the workspace, both `rosrun` and `roslaunch` (after adding a launch file) can ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
.. find the script and start it.

It is much more likely the OP has a typo somewhere, the file is not in the correct location, he forgot to `catkin_make` his workspace, he forgot to `source` the correct `setup.bash` (perhaps used a new terminal) or something else is not entirely correct.

**Comment by [billtheplatypus](https://answers.ros.org/users/35184/billtheplatypus/) on 2018-05-16**:
@gvdhoorn, I do have the setup.bash `source`'d in my bashrc. I also ran catkin_make repeatedly.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
This is probably not the solution, but do please realise that if you have `source .../setup.bash` in your `.bashrc`, it will only actually `source` your workspace if/when you open a new terminal, start `bash` or `source $HOME/.bashrc`. It will not happen automatically whenever your ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
.. workspace changes.

If you haven't `source`d *after* you built your workspace, then new pkgs added afterwards will not be picked up.

**Comment by [billtheplatypus](https://answers.ros.org/users/35184/billtheplatypus/) on 2018-05-16**:
@gcdhoorn I know, and I've both closed and reopened bash, and sourced bashrc again

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:\

> @gcdhoorn I know, and I've both closed and reopened bash, and sourced bashrc again

then I believe we're going to need a little more info. Please tell us how you setup your workspace (paths, layout, etc), what your workflow is, show the contents of your pkg (`ls -al`), etc.

**Comment by [billtheplatypus](https://answers.ros.org/users/35184/billtheplatypus/) on 2018-05-16**:
I'll add that later today

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-16**:
Is what you added your update? I don't see any info describing your workspace setup, layout or exact workflow.

**Comment by [billtheplatypus](https://answers.ros.org/users/35184/billtheplatypus/) on 2018-05-16**:
That wasn't it, but I just figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the issue. I had originally wrote the code for the node in a different directory. When it came time to make the package, i just symlinked the src directory of the package to the directory with the code I had written. For some reason, that breaks it. I removed the symlink and just copied the directory, and now it works great.

---

Originally posted by [billtheplatypus](https://answers.ros.org/users/35184/billtheplatypus/) with karma: 110 on 2018-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-17**:
Good to hear you resolved this.

It was partially why I asked you about your workspace setup though.